# Compile with a reference a dynamically loaded class

Tags: java, dynamic, compiler-construction, classloader

First suppose that I have an abstract class, let's call it AbstractClass.  Suppose

```
public abstract AbstractClass {
    public abstract void F();
}
```

Suppose that I have a class, let's call it ClassA.  ClassA extends AbstractClass.  ClassA is saved in a folder.  (It has to be loaded onto the classpath.)  Now suppose that I am writing a new class within the program,

```
ClassB
```

and I want ClassB to be able to reference ClassA.  Something along the lines of

```
public class ClassB extends AbstractClass {

    ClassA A = new ClassA();

    public void F() {
         A.F();
    }

}
```

Now, I have had no trouble using a class loader to get classA and use it dynamically.  I have also had no problem writing a class like ClassA dynamically based on user input, compiling it within the program (using ecj.jar), and then loading it and calling methods from it.

I cannot figure out though how to reference a dynamically loaded class in a class that I am now writing and compiling dynamically.  I don't know how to write the import, etc.  Loading classA and putting

import classA;

into the classB.java file does not do the trick.

This is my first question on StackOverflow (long time reader), so go easy on me.  Thanks in advance.

--

Context: A program that uses probability distributions entered by the user.  I have an abstract class AbstractDistribution which has abstract methods for the distribution's CDF, PDF, inverse CDF, etc.  So far this has worked well, dynamically writing compiling and loading distributions that extend AbstractDistribution, getting newInstance() of them and using them like any other class.  However, if I have written and dynamically loaded a distribution Dist1, I want to be able to write a Dist2 that can call (for example), the PDF of Dist1.

Comment: why can't class B extends class A ?

Comment: @jasonw, the above example is a really stripped down example.  Suppose I had classes ClassA1 and ClassB1, I might want

` class ClassB {
        ClassA1 A1 = new ClassA1();
        ClassA2 A2 = new ClassA2();
        
        public void F() {
             A1.F();
             A2.F();
        }
    }
`

Comment: okay Richard, some guru will shed some light here I hope :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make `B` refer to `A` directly - make `B` refer to `AbstractClass` and take a reference to an instance in its constructor:

```
public class ClassB extends AbstractClass {

    private final AbstractClass other;

    public ClassB(AbstractClass other) {
        this.other = other;
    }

    public void F() {
         other.F();
    }    
}
```

At this point you need to work out how you're going to get hold of a reference to the other instance of `AbstractClass` (whether it's a `ClassA` or something else) but it does get rid of the direct dependency.

I'm sure there will be more exact details to work out, but if you *can* break the direct dependency like this, it should make the dynamic compilation aspect less of a problem.

Comment: Thank @JohnSkeet.  This isn't quite what I am looking for, as I want users to be able to hard code in the reference. That is, I have JTextFields where they basically define the contents of the different methods to be written to the new class and compiled.  So for example if `ClassA` has already been dynamically written and loaded, I want them to be able to write something like `new ClassA().F()` and have that compile.  This may not be possible.  :(

Comment: @richard: Well it is, so long as you include the dynamically compiled class in the classpath you're using within the compilation. You haven't talked much about the compilation step.

Comment: I got it to work; you were right about the class path of the compiler.  Once I passed `-classpath [directory with dynamically written classes]` into the `options` argument of the `JavaCompiler.getTask(...)` function, it worked **perfectly**.  Thanks.  Now that is sorted out I have to deal with the nightmare of managing the cross-class dependencies my users might create....